# PHP invalid string concatenation with object instance, what error is thrown?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.0

I noticed one of my script fails because of an invalid concatenation between a string and an object instance that doesn't implement `__toString()`. Here's a minimal reproduction:

```php
class Foo { }
$bar = new Foo();
echo "Hello " . $bar . "\n";
echo "OK";
```

This fails on the third line. The strange thing is that I'm not able to catch or detect the error in any way, unlike any other error I encountered since now. It just fails. Here's what I tried that didn't work:

- catch the error wrapping the code inside a `try ... catch` block, trying catching `Exception`, `Error` and `Throwable`;
- registering a shutdown function with `register_shutdown_function()` and using `error_get_last()` inside it, the shutdown function doesn't get called at all;
- calling `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, the shutdown function still doesn't get called.

The only trace is in the output if I use `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`, it ironically says:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Foo could not be converted to string
```

But still, looks like there's no way to catch this programmatically.

Tested in PHP 7.0.22 and PHP 7.0.33.

Comment: The function in https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php#errorexception.examples may help if you want to process it.

Comment: i wonder what could be a real world application for concatenating a newly instantiated object to a string, i haven't tried to do that in anyway possible before, could someone enlighten me with this too

Comment: @Kevin, I think they were just showing it as an example as to how to reproduce the problem.  In reality in could happen after a large amount of processing.

Comment: @NigelRen Many thanks, the duplicate and the manual link look exactly what I was searching for. I focused on the string concatenation instead of the non-catchable catchable error, that's why I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Oddly enough it is actually catchable in PHP 7.4 which tells me it might have something to do with the changes to make `__toString` able to throw exceptions

Comment: @Kevin I just noticed a cron script failing abruptly, without any clue in my logs. I couldn't get the reason until I debugged it step by step, and found that simple error where I mistakenly try to concatenate a variable that is not a string. That wasn't intentional.

Comment: @apokryfos Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @lorenzo-s gotcha thanks for the context, i haven't done any real world application using that way so im curious and apparently, it was done inadvertently